Тип даннных auto
Я не совсем понимаю, что значит данное выражение:
auto ptr = find(ba, ba + 6, str[i]);
Вроде как auto определяет тип данных сам. Но тогда почему я не могу написать
int* ptr = find(ba, ba + 6, str[i]); ?

А кто вам запрещает? пишите int*...

Какой тип вы напишете, например, тут, вместо ????
template<typename T, typename F>
void calc(T& x, F func)
{
    ??? z = func(x);
    ??? y = func(z);
    ....
}

Там, где вы тип знаете точно — вам же никто не запрещает использовать его, а не auto? В чем проблема? Например, никто не мешает написать
std::vector<std::set<std::string>>::const_iterator a = v.begin();

вместо
auto a = v.begin();


Harry, положа руку на сердце, скажите, по вашему мнению с появлением auto программы стали в среднем лучше или хуже?

@avp Я практически не работаю с чужими исходниками, а о своих говорить нескромно :) Но если интересует моя точка зрения на применение auto, то, как и везде, нужно потреблять, но не злоупотреблять. Все хорошо в меру. И auto часто бывает полезен :)
